# Only do action if rectangle exists in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV (and Python) and have managed to get OpenCV to detect my nose and move the mouse using the movement of my nose, but since it looses track of my nose often I want it to fall back to moving using my face instead of my nose if needed. I've managed to draw rectangles around my face and my nose in video.

I tried being cheeky and just putting the loop for my face rectangle in "if cv2.rectangle" (for the nose), but it is always true. My question is how can I create a test to see if nose is detected fallback to move mouse with face, and if nose is re-detected go back to using the nose.

My loops as of now

```
  # Here we draw the square around the nose, face and eyes that is detected.
    for (x,y,w,h) in nose_rect:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)
        if cv2.rectangle:
            m.move(x * 4, y * 4) # TODO: Write and if that goes into face if nose is not visible
            break
        else:
            for (x, y, w, h) in face_rect:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                break

    for (x,y,w,h) in eye_rect:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (205,0,0), 3)
        break
```

I can post my entire program if that helps, I've tried doing a bunch of the OpenCV official tutorials but did not managed to find an answer to my question there.

Thank you for all replies!

PS: I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: what is the value of nose_rect when it doesn't detect the nose?

Comment: they seem to change, but I got "x; 325m y: 195, w: 130, h:59" when trying now this last time.
The values also change whenever I go to another cv2.rectangle Just checking using PyCharm debugger

Comment: okay, what I meant to ask was is there any change in these numbers when it suddenly stops detecting, print it in the loop and see.

Comment: adding 


`  for (x,y,w,h) in nose_rect:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)
        m.move(x * 4, y * 4) # TODO: Write and if that goes into face if nose is not visible
        break
        if nose_rect(x+w+y+h) == (0,0,0,0) :
            print("No nose detected!")
            break`


to the code did not print "no nose detected" when holding my hand over my nose (so the square was not drawn)

Comment: Sorry wrote my previous comment before I saw your latest. 
Holding my hand over my nose simply stops the numbers being outputted. So it seems it saves the numbers and simply does nothing with them as I hold my hand over my nose.

Comment: add a link to your code, preferably a github link. I'll have a look.

Comment: thanks, here is the link from GitHub
[GitHub](https://github.com/AndreasJacobsen/noseCV/blob/master/nose.py)

This is without my print inside of it or the if else

Comment: found the issue. Check the answer below

Comment: Also, as I already forked your code, I have sent you a PR with the exact changes below. Accept it if you like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the snippet you should use in your code-

```
    if(len(nose_rect)>0): 
        print ("Only Nose")
        for (x,y,w,h) in nose_rect:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)
            #Here we say that m (the variable created before, should move the mouse using the x, and y variable from the nose rect.
            # We have acellerated movement speed by 4 to make it possible to navigate the cursor through the whole screen.
            m.move(x * 4, y * 4) # TODO: Write and if that goes into face if nose is not visible
    elif (len(face_rect)>0):
        print ("Only Face")
        for (x,y,w,h) in face_rect:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 3)
    elif (len(face_rect)>0):
        print ("Only Eye")
        for (x,y,w,h) in eye_rect:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (205,0,0), 3)
    else:
        print ("Nothing detected.")
```

Also, for waiting use the time.sleep() method

```
    time.sleep(0.001) # Waiting 1 millisecond to show the next frame.
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):#exit on pressing 'q'
     break
```

Comment: Thank you! And extra thank you for the comments and pull request as well :)

Comment: You're welcome. Appreciated the clean code and hence felt no barrier to give a PR :)